# Loading Set Macro's and Removing Set Macros

Tags: vba, excel

When I open Excel, automatically a workbook is loaded containing macros. I think a binary file? or in a personal macro set? How can I edit this? How do I stop these from loading and perhaps load other general macros instead?

My purpose is to load my most common macros across any workbook at any time so I don't have to go hunting for them each time.

Comment: I'd place your commonly used macros in the Personal.xlsb.  As for removing macros, open the VBEditor (Alt+F11), then look in the workbook modules and worksheets for any code and remove.

Comment: @BruceWayne , thanks bruce, what if I dont have a personal.xlsb or cannot find it?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566). Let me know if you still need some guidance!

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks bruce. Is there any chance you know how to change location of where excel loads personal.xlsb upon startup?

Comment: I highly suggest not changing where `Personal.xlsb` is. Is there a reason you'd want to move it from the default folder?

Comment: @BruceWayne , I have two XLSTART's. so their is confusion. It loads one locaiton but saves to another.

Comment: Open the VB Editor and open the Immediate Window (CTRL+G), and type `Application.StartupPath` and see what it says. It should give you the folder that it's loading when Excel starts.  Or are you saying that it's not saving to the Personal.xlsb located there?

Comment: @BruceWayne I actually get an error when I type that in. `invalid use of property` .  To add, I have 2 folders I notice when i type in XLSTART into the search, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART` and `C:\Users\ladiesman\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`

Comment: Ah, so sorry, type `?Application.StartupPath`.  I believe that it's going to be looking for the Personal.xlsb in the `AppData\Roaming\...\XLSTART` folder.

Comment: @BruceWayne , I get `C:\Users\ladiesman\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` , you were right master. but the problem is, it doesnt seem to load.

Comment: Can you double click the .xlsb in that folder? If it doesn't load, can you explain how so? Is there an error it gives you?

Comment: @BruceWayne , I can open it fine and it loads, seems to save, I guess it just doesn't automatically load into excel on startup.

Comment: Does the *other* Personal.xlsb load? Or none? A quick way to check is to open Excel, go to View -> Macros, and then by "Macros in", see if Personal.xlsb is a choice. From what it sounds like, any Personal.xlsb is *not* in that list, correct?

Comment: @BruceWayne , niether loads I guess,I only have choices of all open workbooks, this workbook and book1. but I did delete the other personal.xlsb in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART`   .. also when i try to record a macro under personal macro workbook it doesnt work saying it must be open for recording.

Comment: Do you have a Personal.xlsb in the `\AppData\Roaming\...\XLSTART` folder?  Does [this thread](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-personal-xlsb-in-excel-2010-does-not-open-on-starting-excel.1049303/) or [this one](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/448694-personal-xlsb-file-not-loading-while-starting-excel.html) help?

Comment: @BruceWayne , thank you master wayne. the 2nd one was able to solve it, that personal.xlsb was disabled for some reason.